# How do you insert multiple rows of data using SQL or PLSQL into a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, sql-insert, oracle-apex-5

I've been struggling with this for days now, but are not able to insert multiple rows at the same time. It's just basic stuff, see below. Working in Oracle Application Express 5.1.4.00.08.

```
insert into historie (mnr, beginjaar, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen) 
values (7499,1988,'01-06-1988','01-07-1989',30,1000,' ');
insert into historie (mnr, beginjaar, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen) 
values (7499,1989,'01-07-1989','01-12-1993',30,1300,' ');
```

It only accepts 1 row at a time, and as soon as I try multiple rows it gives this general error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Workshop, right? Include those commands into a `begin-end` block (and make them PL/SQL instead):

```
begin
  insert into historie ...;
  insert into historie ...;
end;
/
```

and then push the `RUN` button.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I was already trying to make a procedure but made it far too difficult. Bless

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```sql
insert into historie (mnr, beginjaar, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen)
SELECT 7499, 1988, DATE '1988-06-01', DATE '1989-07-01', 30, 1000,' ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7499, 1989, DATE '1989-07-01', DATE '1993-12-01', 30, 1300,' ' FROM DUAL;
```

Or, use `INSERT ALL`:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO historie (mnr, beginjaar, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen)
  VALUES ( 7499, 1988, DATE '1988-06-01', DATE '1989-07-01', 30, 1000,' ' )
INTO historie (mnr, beginjaar, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen) 
  VALUES ( 7499, 1989, DATE '1989-07-01', DATE '1993-12-01', 30, 1300,' ' )
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Don't insert `DATE` values as strings as this requires Oracle to perform an implicit string-to-date conversion and if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter changes then your code will stop working. Instead, either use `TO_DATE` to explicitly perform the conversion or use a date literal (like `DATE '1988-06-01'`).

Also, if the `beginjaar` column should have the same year as the `begindatum` column then use a virtual column rather than duplicating data (as the duplicated data can get out of sync). For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE historie (
  mnr        NUMBER,
  beginjaar  NUMBER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM begindatum ) ) VIRTUAL,
  begindatum DATE,
  einddatum  DATE,
  afd        NUMBER,
  maandsal   NUMBER,
  opmerkingen VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then:

```sql
insert into historie (mnr, begindatum, einddatum, afd, maandsal, opmerkingen)
SELECT 7499, DATE '1988-06-01', DATE '1989-07-01', 30, 1000,' ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7499, DATE '1989-07-01', DATE '1993-12-01', 30, 1300,' ' FROM DUAL;
```

and:

```sql
SELECT * FROM historie;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>  MNR | BEGINJAAR | BEGINDATUM          | EINDDATUM           | AFD | MAANDSAL | OPMERKINGEN
> ---: | --------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | --: | -------: | :----------
> 7499 |      1988 | 1988-06-01 00:00:00 | 1989-07-01 00:00:00 |  30 |     1000 |            
> 7499 |      1989 | 1989-07-01 00:00:00 | 1993-12-01 00:00:00 |  30 |     1300 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ca61853e9a846db61d7c0adce94e37a)*